# Cytoscapejs cose layput give 0 for all nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, cytoscape.js

I am writing a simple javascript using cytoscapejs using nodejs in the terminal. My aim is to get the position of all nodes given node and edge list and layout. I run below code:

```
var cytoscape = require('cytoscape');

var cy = cytoscape({

  elements: [ // list of graph elements to start with
    { // node a
      data: { id: 'a' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'b' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'c' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'd' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'e' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'f' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'g' }
    },
    { // node b
      data: { id: 'h' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'ab', source: 'a', target: 'b' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'bc', source: 'b', target: 'c' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'cd', source: 'c', target: 'd' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'de', source: 'd', target: 'e' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'ef', source: 'e', target: 'f' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'fg', source: 'f', target: 'g' }
    },
    { // edge ab
      data: { id: 'gh', source: 'g', target: 'h' }
    }
  ],

  style: [ // the stylesheet for the graph
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': '#666',
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    },

    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        'width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-color': '#ccc',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {name: "cose",randomize: true}
});

cy.nodes().forEach(function(s){
    console.log(s.position().x)
    console.log(s.position().y)
});
```

When I see the result of the position, it gives 0 for all nodes. If I use other type of layout, it gives some result other than 0. How to properly use cose for layout? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a continuous/asynchronous layout and expecting it to finish like a discrete/synchronous layout.

Wait for the layout to finish.  Use `cy.ready()` if you want to specify the layout at init, or preferably create a [`layout`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) and bind to [`layoutstop`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/graph-events) -- i.e. `layout.on('layoutstop', () => { /* ... */ })`.

Comment: I didn't know Cytoscape run async before. Now I have solved it.